# Selecting text nodes with jQuery code half way there

Tags: jquery, text

ok guys I have this code

```
var text = $('.css .cont_code code');
 text.contents().text(function() {
   $(this).each(function() {
   var cssC = "background , background-color , width , height , float , margin , margin-left , margin-right , margin-top , margin-bottom , contents , border , !important"
  if (text === "cssC")
 { 
  $(this).wrap('<span class="stylesC" />');
  }
})
})
```

Its grabbing all the text node lines, just not the text I am providing in the `var cssC =` code any help would be greatly appreciated never grabbed textNodes with jQuery and know very little on how to write actual javascript like `getElementById` i'm not fluent at that nor jQuery really to be honest.

Basically what I am trying to do is grab the certain text fields I place in the var cssC then if it is found to wrap that in a span with `span class="stylesC" />` The out come should look like this

http://jsfiddle.net/yzpCE/

Comment: As far as I know text nodes cannot be siblings with one another.  That is, if you don't have other elements separating them, you will have to split them on your own

Comment: Hey Explosion long time no see. Problem is it is generated like so `"margin-left:-10px;"<br />"margin-top:10px;"<br />` and well what I am doing is trying to make a syntax highlighter for these forums something easy not to advanced. anyway I could it other way? maybe adding

`var cssC = "background , background-color , width , height , float , margin , margin-left , margin-right , margin-top , margin-bottom , contents , border , !important".replace('/\s/g',|);`

Comment: Can you actually post the *input* on jsfiddle?  It's easier to work with that way

Comment: this is the fiddle of the markup that is generated  
http://jsfiddle.net/YxjnR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/YxjnR/1/

You don't have to do much jQuery work here, but I would split the words in `cssC` and then just do a replace on the html string when you find those words with the same string wrapped in a span.

```
html.replace(new RegExp(this, 'g'), '<span class="stylesC">' + this + '</span>');
```

Comment: wow dude make my code look like pooooooop lol! thanks I have alot more to add to this anyways for jQuery HTML and CSS. Any way we are able to select the `{` `}`?

Comment: also margin-left and anything with margin- won't highlight

Comment: @EasyBB if what you want to do is essentially create a parser for CSS it's going to be complicated no matter what you do.  Take a look at this project that simply parses a CSS file and matches rulesets against whitelists/blacklists.  It's pretty big: https://github.com/ajcrites/csspurify

Comment: ok so I can only do simple? Which is still ok to me. I just want to liven up my codes when I place them on my site.

Comment: @EasyBB if you want to match more words, just add them to `words`: http://jsfiddle.net/YxjnR/2/ -- there are tons of javascript syntax highlighting libraries out there too

Comment: Yeah I know they just don't seem to work on the site I use its weird I tried implementing them and it was garbage. But thanks Explosion you got me off to a good start ;)